# change the font of the body of the mail according to the mailbox

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, fonts

I have a user who would like to change the font of the mail body when sending a mail from a different mailbox. (Office Home and Business 2019)
One of the companies where his email address is located has a dedicated corporate font that he has to use when sending messages.
In the idea it is looking for the same behavior as personalized signatures per mailbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, the default font of the mail body will be applied to all the mailboxes in the current Outlook profile. And this is by design, we could not make changes to it. If necessary, it is suggested to add different mailbox to different Outlook profile so that you could set different default font for them.(Control Panel > Mail > Show profile)